# Material UI: How to change the cursor of a disabled Select field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change a cursor style from `default` to `not-allowed` when a `Select` component is marked as `disabled`. Another easy styling that require overengineering in Material UI and I can't figure out how to do it.

Checking the `CSS` section of the [Select API](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) I've tried to achieve my goal as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl'
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select'
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const styles = () => ({
    formControl: {
        minWidth: 256,
        maxWidth: 256,
    },
    disabled: {
        cursor: 'not-allowed'
    },
    root: {
        cursor: 'not-allowed',
        '&:disabled': {
            cursor: 'not-allowed'
        }
    },
    select: {
        cursor: 'not-allowed',
        '&:disabled': {
            cursor: 'not-allowed'
        }
    }
});

const renderSelectField = ({
  input,
  label,
  meta: { touched, error },
  children,
  classes,
  ...custom
}) => (
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl} error={error && touched}>
        { label && <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel> }
        <Select
            children={children}
            {...input}
            {...custom}
            classes={{
                root: classes.root,
                disabled: classes.disabled,
                select: classes.select
            }}/> 
        }
    </FormControl>
)

export default withStyles(styles)(renderSelectField);
```

It seems that the only way to apply the desired style is by adding `!important` to the disabled style, which is not a really good practice.

Comment: use the ant design select component, it may solve your problem. https://ant.design/components/select/

Comment: You can always inspect the element that is disabled with the developer tools to check the classname. And override/modify the styles for that element in your .css

Comment: @Drusto the class I have to change has an unique identifier .MuiSelect-select-527

Comment: @Valip you can use this css3 selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp `div[class^="MuiSelect"]`

But what is the classname for a disabled one? I mean, how you make difference between one that is disabled and another that is not. Maybe in the  wrapper div? can you provide an example? Js fiddle or similar

Comment: @Drusto This is the complete selector .MuiSelect-select-145.MuiSelect-disabled-149

Comment: @Valip so you can use the css3 selector I mentioned before using 

`div[class^="MuiSelect-disabled"`

Comment: @Drusto that didn't do it, I've created an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-k0h5d

Comment: @Drusto actually it works using `div[class*="MuiSelect-disabled"`. You should add your answer as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this css3 selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

`div[class*="MuiSelect-disabled]`

Answer (score 0):

you can add the property `pointerEvents: 'all !important'`

```
select: {
    '&:disabled': {
      cursor: 'not-allowed',
      pointerEvents: 'all !important'
    }
  }
```